# Titanium AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

I am stuck with this for already 2 weeks. Could anybody tell me how to implement AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (which is already built in Java library for Android) in Appcelerator studio for iOS? I tried Ti.SlowAES and Crypto JS as well but there is nothing PCKS5 Padding in both. The encrypted code is different from the one run by Java. So depressed.
Thanks a lot in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually, it's done. So relieved.
For somebody has the same problem as I did, I wanna make something basic clear.
The first thing is PKCS5 is identical to PKCS7 (just a case of 16 byte of PKCS7).
The second thing is in CBC mode, default padding is PKCS7 (it just adds bytes into encrypted byte to make it %16=0) as AES is symmetric encryption.

My solution works with SlowAES with some modification. You just understand that AES encrypt bytes. So no matter u put the input (String), U have to convert to Bytes to encrypted. The encrypted cipher then have to convert from bytes to string. So use some convert function. The encrypted bytes by SlowAES are correct. The problems are only the convert to base64, HexString,...

Comment: CBC mode has nothing to do with PKCS7, they are not related. You can use CBC mode with or without PKCS7 and PKCS7 can be used with ECB mode. PKCS7 add bytes that have as their value the number of bytes added and if the input is a multiple of the block size an extra block is added. See [Wikipedia PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). CBC mode uses an iv (initialization vector) and many implementations provide a default of all 0x00 values and pad a short iv with 0x00 values. It is best to explicitly supply an iv.

Comment: Hi Trang, I need to use aes decryption in my ios app but i do not know how to decrypt it so will you please tell me how can i decrypt the data step by step?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is PKCS#5 vs PKCS#7 padding they are same.

The only difference is in the specification: PKCS#5 padding is identical to PKCS#7 padding, except that it has only been defined for block ciphers that use a 64-bit (8 byte) block size and PKCS#7 is defined for up to 255 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestions for me to do that by Ti.SlowAES?

Comment: I woukd not use Ti.SlowAES because of the following: 1. There is no documentation on it's use, one should not hav e to read the code to find out how to use it. 2. There is no documetation in inter-operabilitr. 3. It uses an undocumented key expansion. 4. It is an implementation in JS that has not been certified. 5. It may have bugs and/or backdoors. 6. Find a library that meets at least items 1-3.